# What is does the build information contain in conda env export?

Tags: anaconda, conda

When using `conda env export` it is possible to remove the build information with `--no-build`:

```
...
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
  - attrs=19.3.0=py_0
  - backcall=0.1.0=py37_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.8.2=py37_0
  - biopython=1.76=py37h7b6447c_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - bleach=3.1.0=py37_0
...
```

and with `--no-build`

```
dependencies:
  - _libgcc_mutex=0.1
  - attrs=19.3.0
  - backcall=0.1.0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.8.2
  - biopython=1.76
  - blas=1.0
  - bleach=3.1.0
  - bzip2=1.0.8
  - ca-certificates=2020.1.1
```

Could you explain in detail what exactly is this build information? The compiler and its version? What else is in there?

Answer (score 1):

The build information is a hash of the variant keys in the recipe. Quoting the docs:

> The takeaway message is that hashes will appear when binary compatibility matters, but not when it doesn't.

and

> As of conda-build 3.1.0, this hashing scheme has been simplified. A hash will be added if all of these are true for any dependency:
>
> - Package is an explicit dependency in build, host, or run deps.
> - Package has a matching entry in conda_build_config.yaml which is a pin to a specific version, not a lower bound.
> - That package is not ignored by ignore_version.
>
> OR
>
> - Package uses `{{ compiler() }}` Jinja2 function.

The documentation is here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/variants.html#differentiating-packages-built-with-different-variants There's also a blog post (that I can't find now) with some more information.

Comment: So bottom line - an unassuming user trying to create an universal env.yaml file.... do they want to include the cache or not?

Comment: Universal meaning cross-platform? No, you do not want to include the hash. But you're sacrificing some reproducibility in that case.