What do the build strings mean?
In anaconda, what do the strings mean that appear at the end of the line, "[package name]=[version]=[MYSTERY STRING]"? This is an example requirements.txt:
# This file may be used to create an environment using:
# $ conda create --name <env> --file <this file>
# platform: linux-64
_libgcc_mutex=0.1=main
_openmp_mutex=5.1=1_gnu
zstd==1.5.5=hc292b87_0
zstandard==0.22.0=pypi_0
zlib==1.2.13=h5eee18b_0

EDIT: this is not a duplicate because the other questions answer this only for strings starting with "py[version]". This does not answer it for main, h5eee18b_0, 1_gnu, etc.

This question is similar to: What is after second = in conda dependencies yml. Example pandas=1.2.4=py38h1abd341_0. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Also relevant, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874816/what-is-the-meaning-of-condas-build-string and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45874816/what-is-the-meaning-of-condas-build-string

this is not a duplicate because the other questions answer this only for strings starting with "py[version]". This does not answer it for main, h5eee18b_0, 1_gnu, etc.

Sorry, I linked twice to the same question. In any case, does this answer it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61213160/what-is-does-the-build-information-contain-in-conda-env-export Also this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65020285/2449192  Regardless, the answer is the same. The last string is the hash, if it doesn't start with pyXX then Python isn't a dependency.

Sorry, I said "The last string is the hash", I should have said: The last string is the build string. If it doesn't start with pyXX then Python isn't a dependency for that package. If it contains some text after an h, that is a hash of some of the version constraints, as answered in some of the questions I linked to. In any case, the answer is the same as the duplicate suggestion.
